# trigger component scan from a application for an included spring boot jar using extra annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to publish a Spring boot based jar which should be consumed in other Spring/Spring boot based applications.
In my reuse jar I have a class(BusinessConfig) annotated with @Configuration and it gives out two beans. This class is in the base package of the reuse jar.

```
 @Configuration
public class BusinessConfig {
    @Bean(name = "BusinessRepoManager")
    public BusinessRepoManager businessRepoManager(){
       return BusinessRepoManager.getInstance();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "CustomerManager")
    @Scope("request")
    public CustomerManager customerManager(BusinessRepoManager busrepoManager){
        return CustomerManager.getInstance();
    }

}
```

In the second application, I have added the dependency and in the application class I have the statement

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BusinessConfig.class})
```

to inform Spring context to look for beans provided in BusinessConfig class as well.

This works well, as I could see the beans getting created.

Is there any possibility to simplify this, should all consuming applications know the class name in which my configuration exists/package name.
I tried creating a custom annotation in the jar project and used that in the consuming application.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BusinessConfig.class})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Component
public @interface EnableDemoBusiness {

}
```

Then in my consuming application I just added

```
 @EnableDemoBusiness
    @SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this work ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

## Option 1

You can turn your class into "auto-configuration", by creating a `META-INF/spring.factories` file in your jar with the following content:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.your.package.BusinessConfig
```

Now in applications using your jar if `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotations are used, your configuration will be processed and the beans created.

You might want to annotate your configuration with some `@ConditionalXXX` annotations if required to give applications that use your jar more control.

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) for more information.

## Options 2

You can create a custom `@EnableXXX` annotation like you attempted.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(com.your.package.BusinessConfig.class)
public @interface EnableDemoBusiness {

}
```

Comment: Great it works perfectly. As a derived question, I have the following.
a. The consuming application has its context and that is where my beans are getting created, the reuse jar has no context on its own rite ?

b. I use a request scoped bean, Can I validate whether there is a WebApplicationContext and only then allow bean creation ? Should I do it via the @ConditionalXXX annotations to detect for a WebBasedApplicationContext bean ?

Comment: @siva you can use `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` for that bean. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnWebApplication.html